# Error while compiling rviz

Tags: rviz, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Previously I was using rviz from `sudo apt-get install ros-groovy-rviz` and it encounters some error when I trying to view laser data. So I decided to git clone it and compile the version 1.9.35 of rviz. However, when I catkin_make the rviz it shows me the error below

```
Linking CXX executable /home/viki/catkin_ws/devel/lib/rviz/rviz
[ 92%] Built target default_plugin
Linking CXX executable /home/viki/catkin_ws/devel/lib/rviz/image_view
/home/viki/catkin_ws/devel/lib/librviz.so: undefined reference to `image_transport::ImageTransport::~ImageTransport()'
/home/viki/catkin_ws/devel/lib/librviz.so: undefined reference to `image_transport::ImageTransport::ImageTransport(ros::NodeHandle const&)'
/home/viki/catkin_ws/devel/lib/librviz.so: undefined reference to `image_transport::ImageTransport::subscribe(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, unsigned int, boost::function<void (boost::shared_ptr<sensor_msgs::Image_<std::allocator<void> > const> const&)> const&, boost::shared_ptr<void> const&, image_transport::TransportHints const&)'
/home/viki/catkin_ws/devel/lib/librviz.so: undefined reference to `image_transport::Subscriber::shutdown()'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [/home/viki/catkin_ws/devel/lib/rviz/rviz] Error 1
make[1]: *** [rviz/src/rviz/CMakeFiles/executable.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
CMakeFiles/rviz_image_view.dir/image_view.cpp.o: In function `ImageView':
/home/viki/catkin_ws/src/rviz/src/image_view/image_view.cpp:56: undefined reference to `image_transport::ImageTransport::ImageTransport(ros::NodeHandle const&)'
/home/viki/catkin_ws/src/rviz/src/image_view/image_view.cpp:56: undefined reference to `image_transport::ImageTransport::~ImageTransport()'
CMakeFiles/rviz_image_view.dir/image_view.cpp.o: In function `~ImageView':
/home/viki/catkin_ws/src/rviz/src/image_view/image_view.cpp:62: undefined reference to `image_transport::ImageTransport::~ImageTransport()'
/home/viki/catkin_ws/src/rviz/src/image_view/image_view.cpp:62: undefined reference to `image_transport::ImageTransport::~ImageTransport()'
CMakeFiles/rviz_image_view.dir/image_view.cpp.o: In function `image_transport::SubscriberFilter::subscribe(image_transport::ImageTransport&, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, unsigned int, image_transport::TransportHints const&)':
/opt/ros/groovy/include/image_transport/subscriber_filter.h:111: undefined reference to `image_transport::ImageTransport::subscribe(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, unsigned int, boost::function<void (boost::shared_ptr<sensor_msgs::Image_<std::allocator<void> > const> const&)> const&, boost::shared_ptr<void> const&, image_transport::TransportHints const&)'
CMakeFiles/rviz_image_view.dir/image_view.cpp.o: In function `image_transport::SubscriberFilter::unsubscribe()':
/opt/ros/groovy/include/image_transport/subscriber_filter.h:119: undefined reference to `image_transport::Subscriber::shutdown()'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [/home/viki/catkin_ws/devel/lib/rviz/image_view] Error 1
make[1]: *** [rviz/src/image_view/CMakeFiles/rviz_image_view.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
Invoking "make" failed
```

At first I thought it was something to do with the image_transport package and so after I do source `/opt/ros/groovy/setup.bash` , I can rosrun image_transport but the error still remain the same. Do anyone know how to solve it? Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/133766/error-while-compiling-rviz/) by [zero1985](https://answers.ros.org/users/6926/zero1985/) on ROS Answers with karma: 100 on 2014-02-26

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can get the source code from git and check out branch 1.9.35. It's a patch to resolve this issue. Read more [here](https://github.com/ros-visualization/rviz/issues/725).

```
cd ~/catkin_ws/src
git clone https://github.com/ros-visualization/rviz.git
cd rviz
git checkout 1.9.35
cd ../..
catkin_make
```

EDIT: If this doesn't work, it's likely that something went wrong with your ROS installation. You might want to try to reinstall ROS!

---

Originally posted by [Andrew.A](https://answers.ros.org/users/5270/andrew.a/) with karma: 324 on 2014-02-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2